# Object oriented programming Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

I am trying to design a website through object oriented programming with codeigniter.

I'm having a little concerns about how i can create a instance of an object and keep it **persistent** and **available** throughout some specific controllers of even different methods of the same controller.

Imagine that i have a **User** class with all it's properties and methods and i want to create a instance of it. Knowing that in a private area that instance should be already created and available, what is the best way to  access it by different methods or controllers from a private area?

Should i create a instance of it and access from MY_private_controller inheritance? Does the instance "survives" or a method in MY_private_controller needs to create a new one for each different method i call?
What is the best practice in your experience with php to achieve a persistent instance?

Thank you

Comment: "PHP has an execution model where each web request from the host environment generates a new, fresh PHP environment which is destroyed when the request is completed."

I see now. I can always store it in session. A little dirty. Is this common in other web development languages?

Comment: the internet is a "stateless protocol". so you are either passing a "token" or you are setting/retrieving a value in the users cookie. otherwise you will get more help if you can write out a more specific example of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each method in your controller will be invoked to process different requests from the web browser, you have no other option than create the `User` instance each time.

This is because php application life-cycle is this:

- browser sends a request to the web-server
- web-server forwards the request to php
- php runs your entry script
- inside the endtry script your application starts
- application processes the request and returns the response
- application finishes
- web-server sends the response back

So on every request your application starts from the scratch, processes the request and dies. Check [PHP is meant to die](http://software-gunslinger.tumblr.com/post/47131406821/php-is-meant-to-die).

Comment: with respect - that article is (trash) talking about the limits of using php for large enterprise applications. OP stated he is a solo developer creating his first website.

Comment: @cartalot if I got the OPs question right, the main problem is that he doesn't understand the php application lifecycle. And IMO the article explains it clearly, both good and bad sides.

Answer (score 0):

first return the user from a model. you can do this anywhere, just put it in an if condition so if the user is not found it can handle the error. if the user should already be logged in then you can return the user in the controller constructor. so for example a controller named Useradmin

```
class Useradmin extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model( 'users' );

       // if we do not get a user back, then redirect to login
       if( ! $this->user = $this->users->returnActiveUser() )
       {   
        redirect("login/index") ;
       } 


    }
```

so now $this->user will be available for any method in the controller, any models those methods call, and any views that are loaded. you can also update $this->user and it will use the updated version for any subsequent method.